# Avoiding infinite recursion when calculating value of database view column depending on another view column

Tags: database, postgresql, recursion, sql-view, dynamic-columns

I have the following case of using PostgreSQL view. I have to dynamically calculated the value of view column depending of the value of another dynamically calculated view column. Here is simplified version of the code:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE test
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  value integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (1, 13),
  (2, 42);

CREATE FUNCTION inc(value integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    RETURN value + 1;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE FUNCTION double(id integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    local_value integer;
  BEGIN
    SELECT value_1 INTO local_value
    FROM test_view WHERE double.id = test_view.id;

    RETURN 2 * local_value;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE VIEW test_view AS
  SELECT *,
         inc(test.value) AS value_1,
         double(test.id) AS value_2
  FROM test;

COMMIT;
```

But this code falls in infinite recursion because of the following statement in the second function.

```
SELECT value_1 INTO local_value
FROM test_view WHERE double.id = test_view.id;
```

The exact error is the following:

```
ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth
(currently  2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inc(integer) line 3 at RETURN
SQL statement "SELECT value_1 FROM test_view WHERE double.id = test_view.id"
 PL/pgSQL function double(integer) line 5 at SQL statement
```

The problem can easily be overcome by using second view. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION double(value integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    RETURN 2 * value;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE VIEW test_view_1 AS
  SELECT *,
         inc(test.value) AS value_1
  FROM test;

CREATE VIEW test_view_2 AS
  SELECT *,
         double(test_view_1.value_1) AS value_2
  FROM test_view_1;
```

But I don't like this approach because it requires creating of second view. It not scales in the case I have **n** different values each depending of the previous one. Then I must have **n** different views.

Is it possible to solve the problem with only one view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?

```
CREATE FUNCTION inc(value integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    RETURN value + 1;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE FUNCTION double(value integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    RETURN 2 * value;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE VIEW test_view AS
  SELECT *,double(value_1) AS value_2 FROM 
(SELECT *,
    inc(test.value) AS value_1
  FROM test) x;

select * from test_view;
```

Did i miss something from OP?

You can do it in on step

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION incdouble(value integer)
  RETURNS RECORD AS
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
     linc integer;
     ret  RECORD;  
  BEGIN
    linc := value + 1;
    SELECT linc,linc*2 INTO ret;
    RETURN ret;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
select * from test t,incdouble(t.value) as (i integer ,d integer)
```